# desgin of table for book with multipe categories

Tags: sql

I have 2 table one for book info and other with categories the book May have multipe categories but I can't think of A way to get the id of each category as foreign key in the book table

```
Book table
=========
id
Bookname
Category1
Category2

CATEGORIES table
=========
id
Action
Adventure 
Romance
```

If by my idea I must have many columns for the categories or is thier other way Iam new to all of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical design for many-to-many case is

```
Books table
=========
id
Bookname

CATEGORIES table
=========
id
categoryname

Book_Categories
=========
BookId
CategoryId
```

Comment: How can I make relationships between tables like this

Comment: A `Book_Categories` row refers to a  book and  acategory. This way `Book_Categories` keeps the  relationship.